# Why does pip install not work for catboost?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, catboost

I have to install catboost but can not make it by `pip install catboost`.

There is not catboost library in Anaconda, so pip in the one way.

The error message is:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost <for version: >
No matching distribution found for catboost.
```

Python version is 3.6.3.

Screenshot of error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3SMJ.jpg)

I've tried :

```
pip install catboost==0.12.2
pip install catboost==0.12.1.1
pip install catboost==0.12.1
pip install catboost==0.12.0
```

and

```
pip install catboost==0.11.0
pip install catboost==0.10.2
```

None of these works.

Why does this problem appeared and is there another way to install catboost?

Comment: What bit version of python are you using? Chances are its 32

Comment: Yes, it is 32 bit

Comment: I ran into the same issue with Python version 3.11.0. The issue was fixed with Python version 3.9.13.

Comment: Still a problem for me for `Python 3.11.2`

Comment: @AlonSamuel catboost does not yet support `python 3.11.2`.  https://pypi.org/project/catboost/#files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-installation.html)

***Installation is only supported by the 64-bit version of Python.***

You need to reinstall the 64 bit version of python to use the cat boost package

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but it was mainly related to Docker because the error was only occurring when I was trying to install it through a docker - it turned out there is something related to M1 Apple architecture and the solution was to modify the docker command as following

`docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64 -t ${IMAGE_TAG} -f Dockerfile`

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was I was developing on an M1 Mac. Trying to install as root, using conda and using docker images were all unsuccessful.

The fix I found was using the amd64 docker image as my base. The dockerfile code was:

```
FROM amd64/python:3.9-buster

RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install catboost
```

Can't exactly remember how I arrived at the above code, but thanks to https://github.com/prabodh1194 for putting this together. A dockerfile with this code can be found here (as of 25NOV2021) https://github.com/prabodh1194/docker_images/blob/main/catboost/0.26/Dockerfile

Comment: @Willian Ashform you said using arm64 but then posted a dockerfile with amd64 
did you mean arm64/python:3.9-buster

Comment: Apologies, typo! Edited.

Comment: actually docker on arm knows how to emulate amd. so this would also work

Answer (score 1):

in my case, a virtual environment was using an old version of pip and a simple upgrade of pip worked!

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```