# Why does pip install not work for catboost? Problem with python distribution

Tags: python, pip, package, pythonpath, catboost

I have to install catboost but can not make it by pip install catboost. Pip sad 'No matching distribution found for catboost' but that is not as i think.

I read this question [Why does pip install not work for catboost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598558/why-does-pip-install-not-work-for-catboost)
and made sure that i had use pyhon x64, and can install librareis using pip.

The cmd output:

```
C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>python.exe -m pip install cx_oracle
Collecting cx_oracle
Using cached cx_Oracle-8.3.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: cx_oracle
Successfully installed cx_oracle-8.3.0

C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>python
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) \[MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)\] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> exit()

C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>python.exe -m pip install catboost
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost (from versions: 0.1.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost
```

May by the problem in PATH because i have not the administre privilege to check this out but during the pyhton instalation i confirmed adding python to path.

Pip version is:

`C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311>python -m pip -V pip 23.0 from C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)`

What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the solution it's very simple, catboost is not supported for python 3.11 now

Check here https://pypi.org/project/catboost/#files

Comment: A side comment: upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, now called [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).